# PHPmailer stop sending email suddenly from localhost or server AWS

Tags: php, phpmailer

Good day, I know my post will be duplicate i have seen many related post regards of my problem and i get feed up none of all are working with me. the code was working fine by sending email to any email, suddenly stop sending email to any email, i change gmail password and i allow low secure in gmail account but still not working, i follow the guideline and troubleshoot [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) still hopeless, can someone just tell me where is the wrong?? port and ssl, everything are same guideline. code is here:

```
    <?php

require_once("mail_configuration.php");
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$emailBody = "<div><br><br><p>Click this link to recover your password<br><br><br></p>Regards,<br> Admin VMAWS</div>";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port     = 465;
$mail->Username = 'vmaws@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = "secret"; 
$mail->Host     = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
$mail->Mailer   = MAILER;

$mail->SetFrom(SERDER_EMAIL, SENDER_NAME);
$mail->AddReplyTo(SERDER_EMAIL, SENDER_NAME);
$mail->ReturnPath=SERDER_EMAIL; 
$mail->AddAddress($user["email"]);
$mail->Subject = "Forgot Password Recovery";        
$mail->MsgHTML($emailBody);
$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error_message = 'Problem in Sending Password Recovery Email';
} else {
    $success_message = 'Please check your email to reset password!';
}

?>
```

code of configuration:

```
    <?php


define("PORT", "465"); // port number
define("MAIL_USERNAME", "vmaws@gmail.com"); // smtp usernmae
define("MAIL_PASSWORD", "secret"); // smtp password
define("MAIL_HOST", "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"); // smtp host
define("MAILER", "smtp");

define("SENDER_NAME", "VMAWS");
define("SERDER_EMAIL", "vmaws");
?>
```

i'm using appserv with  PHP 5.6.22v

Comment: You have a typo in your user name - `vmaws@gmai.com`? And why are you using old versions of both PHP and PHPMailer? As you know from the docs, the combination of `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 465` will not work. I really suggest you start again using one of the examples that doesn't make all these basic mistakes.

Comment: yes sir, its my username, is there any update?? because im using this code since long time and it was working prefect

Comment: No, it's not your username - it should be `gmail.com`, not `gmai.com`. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what the server is saying. Again, this is all in the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: yes sir its gmail.sorry i was type wrong, but still not working not send any email

Comment: I can’t help you if you don’t do the things I suggest.